# Derivative of $Axb^TC$ with respect to x

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am trying to find the following derivative:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( Axb^TC \right)$$

where $A, C \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $x, b \in \mathbb R^{n \times 1}$. $A,C,b$ are independent of $x$. So far, I was not able to find any identities that can help me here.

Comment: $(Axb^TC)_{ij}=(Ax)_i (b^T C)_j$, so $\frac{\partial (Axb^TC)_{ij}}{\partial x_k} = (b^T C)_j \frac{\partial (Ax)_i}{\partial x_k}=(b^T C)_j a_{ik}$. Note that this depends on 3 indices, since you differentiated a rank 2 tensor with respect to a rank 1 tensor, so you got a rank 3 tensor.

Comment: It will also be some tensor product of a matrix and a vector since it is the derivative of a matrix w.r.t a vector. The derivative of a rank 2 tensor w.r.t. a rank 1 tensor is a rank 3 tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to use [index notation](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~pmvs/courses/mcl702/notation.pdf) and work with the individual components.
$$\eqalign{
Y_{im} &= A_{ij}(x_{j})b_{k}C_{km} \\
G_{imp} =\; 
\frac{\partial Y_{im}}{\partial x_p}
 &= A_{ij}\big(\delta_{jp}\big)b_{k}C_{km} 
 &= A_{ip}b_{k}C_{km} \\
}$$
Since $G$ requires **three** free indexes, it is called a **third**-order tensor.